# Not getting detailed error log for java application on Tomcat on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-web-app-service, catalina

We deployed a java web application (WAR file) onto an Azure App Service with newest Tomcat (8.5). The WAR file is detected by Azure but on startup we are seeing the following in the catalina.*date*.log

> 06-Feb-2018 07:57:24.494 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
>   06-Feb-2018 07:57:24.512 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
>   06-Feb-2018 07:57:27.697 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\myapp.war]
>   06-Feb-2018 07:59:16.570 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. **Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file**
>   06-Feb-2018 07:59:16.570 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/myapp] startup failed due to previous errors
>   06-Feb-2018 07:59:16.629 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\myapp.war] has finished in [108,932] ms

We cannot find this log file anywhere. We have set all possible logging settings to verbose. Should this be a separate file or are some logging settings missing?

We also see the follwing row

> 06-Feb-2018 12:00:43.922 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=**D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\conf\logging.properties**

It is not possible for us to change this file.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web services are deployed to a Windows Server 2016.

You can access the log files and change the location of the log files using

- Open the url `https://<app service name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` {or choose Menu > Debug Console  > CMD)
- Type the `dir` command to go the location of the tomcat install. For example `dir D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.5.6\conf`
- Alternatively you can also click on the folder name dispalyed above the command/terminal
- In your case, to enable detailed logging, open `logging.properties` under `\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.5.6\conf` and set `1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE`. You can read more info at [Documentation on Apache Tomcat 8.5 Logging](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html#Access_logging)

Sample screen from my Tomcat setup as a webservice:

[image: Console to view tomcat webservice]

[image: Select edit option to update file contents]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I get "Access denied" when trying to save the logging.properties file. In the file I already had the logging row 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE. This is AsyncFileHandler and not FileHandler. Is that ok?

Comment: Should be ok. I have not seen a difference. But have to see why you are not able to edit the file.